# Printing out frequency of letters instead of how many times?

Tags: java, arrays, frequency

I'm trying to change my code so that it prints how the frequency of the letters and not how many there is e.g. "I am a man I am a man" should give the same answer as "I am a man" since the relative proportions of each letter to the whole sequence is the same.

So the desired output would be:

Letter A: Count: 0.43
Letter I: Count: 0.14
Letter M: Count: 0.29
Letter N: Count: 0.14

So the count will always add up to 1.0.

At the moment, my code just counts and displays how many times the letter appears, is this simple to change?

//

Comment: Divide the numbers by the `String` length? What's the issue?

Comment: The frequency of a letter is the count of that letter divided by the count of all the letters, not including spaces.  Multiply that number by 100 to get the percentage.

Comment: You should try to rephrase your requirement. Make it more specific - by doing so you should be able to figure out the required computations; and from there it should be easy to change the program. You will not learn much  from just picking up the answers you get here.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this to get the percent of total characters:

```
int total = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < lettersArray.length; i ++)
{
    total += letterArray[i];
}

for (char characters = 'a'; characters <= 'z'; characters++) {
    int index = characters - 'a';
    //print out the analysis
    System.out.println("'" + characters + "' entered " + (((double)letterArray[index] / (double)total)) 
            + " times");
}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("'" + characters + "' entered " + letterArray[index] /         
                (double)line.length() + " times");
```